# Why do I get a $ sign in decompiled java classes full with errors?

Tags: java, eclipse, anonymous

I decompiled my lost apk and got all the resources and all java classes, but the problem is that I got all the .java files with errors and with dollar signs? I know these are anonymous java classes, but how to fix these errors? I can't find a way to do that... Please help

Comment: What errors? You need to provide more information.

Comment: For e.g. eclipse underlines a semi-colomn :"}" or marks "debug" as an error... It's weird because it's functional and right code! Please help @August

Comment: If it's functional and right, what **are** you asking?

Comment: It was functional before I decompiled it but now that I decompiled it, I get all errors @ElliottFrisch

Comment: I am asking how to get rid of all these correct errors that eclipse is underlining @ElliottFrisch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're seeing is Java's internal representation of the anonymous inner classes. Java implements these by creating classes with generated names, which -- like all inner classes -- are based on adding $ and a suffix to the name of the containing class. (There are some other changes made to support the inner class's ability to refer back to its containing context.)

Apparently whichever decompiler you used didn't attempt to reverse that rewrite. That isn't very surprising; I haven't yet seen one that did handle this situation correctly, and some don't even handle constructors correctly (leaving them with their generated function name, <init>(). Unfortunately, compilation of any language always involves discarding some information, and decompilation will generally *not* be able to reconstruct the original code -- and may not be able to reconstruct syntactically correct code, since the object code is generally allowed to do things that the source language can't. You should expect to have to manually edit the decompiler's output.

If you're just trying to get the code running, you may be able to do so by replacing the generated class and function names with ones which are acceptable to Java syntax (as opposed to the less-restricted JRE). If you actually want to turn the generated classes back into anonymous inner classes, you'll have to do that manually as well.

Or you can try to find a decompiler which is better at handling this case and isn't worse at handling other cases. Good luck; if you do find one, let us know.

(The real answer here is to be *extremely* careful not to lose your source code. The best thing that can be said about decompilers is that they're usually better than trying to directly read the instructions.)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. But there is one thing i didnt understand, to run my code, should I delete the generated codes?

Comment: No, you should make the generated code work, either by fixing its class and function names or by manually rewriting it back into the inner class form.

Comment: And bu fixing class and function names, you mean by removing the $ signs? @keshlam

Comment: You may be able to get away with just removing the $ characters, or changing them to _ or something else that's legal in Java source. Or you may not, if that would cause them to collide with your other classes. If it was easy and obvious, the decompiler would have done it for you; unfortunately it requires that a human make some decisions.

Comment: Thanks a lot @keshlam I will tell you what happens :)